# Zend Framework 1 app inside another app

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, ssl

I have a Zend Framework app configured on a subdomain, with a SSL cert. I would like to reuse the SSL cert, instead of buying another one for the admin app.

My main Zend app URL is something like this:

```
https://system.mysite.com
```

I would like to access the another app like this:

```
https://system.mysite.com/control
```

I could have done this, but my SSL cert only allows one subdomain:

```
https://control.mysite.com
```

How can I achieve this?

My server is Apache.